# Input List Selection Changed Event

Tags: html, list, events, input, html-datalist

I have this example:

```
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Google Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

I need to catch an event, when the user **selects option (with mouse or keyboard).**

I tried to do `onchange="MySuperFunction();"`, but this works only when an item is selected and then the list is unfocused.

Comment: hope this will help you 
[try this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25616981/3782212

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `input` event should work for what you need.  As I understand, you can't use a datalist directly, but it is connected to an input by the `list` attribute.  This event binding would go on that input:

```
document.getElementById('browsers-input').addEventListener('input', function (event) {
   if (event.inputType == 'insertReplacementText')
       console.log('autocomplete option selected'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vccfv/

Comment: This responds to not just datalist-related events but any change in the input, including when user types their own text.

Answer (score 2):

To get the same effect of "Explosion Pills" solution using JQuery style:

```
$("#browsers-input").on("input", MySuperFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usin `jQuery` you could use `.change` http://jquery.com/

```
$('datalist#browsers').change(MySuperFunction);
```

or

```
$('datalist#browsers').change(function(){
  // stuff
});
```

Comment: that's why I suggested it with a link to the jQuery page, if you think this is overkill, then suggest to not use it

Comment: i using jquery. but not in sample. hmm, i tried simply $('#browsers').change(function(){alert();}); don`t works :(

Comment: what does `<datalist id="browsers" onchange="alert('martriay is awesome');">` do?

Comment: nothing, i read some docs, maybe reason that datalist is only container for data, not user interface element. maybe need to do something with input list events?

Comment: Not on datalist do it on the input that datalist uses.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a parenthesis or two.