# How to display only the text in datalist HTML5 and not the value?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-datalist

Here is an example:

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">1</option>
    <option value="Firefox">2</option>
    <option value="Chrome">3</option>
    <option value="Opera">4</option>
    <option value="Safari">5</option>
</datalist>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7ehtqjd/1/

What I want to achieve is when I click on the input element the *value* would not be displayed, but ONLY the *text* (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). I.e. the value should be *hidden* like it is with a general dropdown (`<select>` element).

This autocomplete feature is necessary, else I would have gone with the normal dropdown.

Comment: You can move `value` to another parameter (for example, `data-value`) and set 1,2,3,4,5 as `value`.

Comment: But i need to send the value to the back end using jquery.

Comment: You can send `data-value` instead of `value`

Comment: And i just noticed the value is not read

Comment: And can u tell me how to send data-value,
i use - $("#browsers").val()

Comment: check this fiddle, yours, but Altered it `http://jsfiddle.net/Lfgknh78/`

Comment: U have removed the text completely and the tyoe of text is showing as an error

Comment: @Cerebus1504 Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7ehtqjd/3/).

Comment: last fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yy7j0xLy/

Comment: @Pierre - I got to display the ctext in the dropdown. Not the value.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Edit, updated

Following Regent

Try (v3)

html

```
<input id="selected" list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option data-value="InternetExplorer" value="1"></option>
    <option data-value="Firefox" value="2"></option>
    <option data-value="Chrome" value="3"></option>
    <option data-value="Opera" value="4"></option>
    <option data-value="Safari" value="5"></option>
</datalist>
<input id="submit" type="submit">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var data = {}; 
$("#browsers option").each(function(i,el) {  
   data[$(el).data("value")] = $(el).val();
});
// `data` : object of `data-value` : `value`
console.log(data, $("#browsers option").val());


    $('#submit').click(function()
    {
        var value = $('#selected').val();
        alert($('#browsers [value="' + value + '"]').data('value'));
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/j7ehtqjd/13/

Comment: How to retrieve value and send
earlier i used to type
$("#browsers").val().

Comment: @Cerebus1504 Well, maybe [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7ehtqjd/3/) from my question's comment should be added to answer for its completeness

Comment: Ok i will try i am not getting it

Comment: is it possible not to mention the data-value and it takes it dynamically as we choose ?

Comment: @Cerebus1504 what do you mean? We take `data-value` dynamically based on `value` we have chosen. @guest271314, I hope answer is now sufficient for OP. At least I voted up.

Comment: the "$('#browsers [value="' + value + '"]').data('value')"-part did the whole trick for my problem :)

Answer (score 4):

A quite messy method for doing this without dependencies like jQuery (*edit: I realise that jQuery is being used by the OP, but this method will integrate fine with or without jQuery, so might helps others who are not*).

First, swap your value and text nodes around, like so:

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="my_input">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">1</option>
    <option value="Firefox">2</option>
    <option value="Chrome">3</option>
    <option value="Opera">4</option>
    <option value="Safari">5</option>
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
```

This ensures that the input always shows the correct value for the user. Then add in some JavaScript to check the text node of the corresponding value, like so:

```
let $input = document.getElementById('my_input');
let $datalist = document.getElementById('browsers');

$input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let _value = null;

  let input_value = $input.value;
  let options = $datalist.children;
  let i = options.length;

  while(i--) {
    let option = options[i];

    if(option.value == input_value) {
      _value = option.textContent;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(_value == null) {
    console.warn('Value does not exist');
    return false;
  }

  console.log('The value is:', _value );
});
```

You can also change the `'change'` event listener to `'keyup'` too, to get real-time feedback. And instead of `console.log('The value is:', _value )` you can simply add in an additional `hidden` input to store the value, thus allowing you to send both the value and id.

This uses modern JavaScript notation, but to make it backward compatible just need to change the `'change', () => {` call to `'change', function() {` and change `let` to `var`.

## Updated: using ES6

A slightly more up-to-date answer than above

```js
const input = document.getElementById('my_input');
const list = document.getElementById('browsers');

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const {value: inputVal} = input
  const children = Array.from(list.children)

  // Fetch matched elem
  const [matchedElem] = children.filter(({value}) => value === inputVal)
  
  // If element doesn't exist, no matches
  if(!matchedElem) {
    console.log('No matches found')
    
    return
  }
  
  // Do whatever
  console.log('Matched value for', matchedElem.value, 'is', matchedElem.textContent)
});
```

```html
<input type="search" list="browsers" name="browser" id="my_input">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">1</option>
  <option value="Firefox">2</option>
  <option value="Chrome">3</option>
  <option value="Opera">4</option>
  <option value="Safari">5</option>
</datalist>

<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

I though I would add a shorter Vanilla JS version of these answers.  This will hide the true value, but when the item is submitted, it will replace it with your desired value on the form.

````
<input id="selected" list="browsers" name="browser" >
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option data-value="InternetExplorer" value="1"></option>
    <option data-value="Firefox" value="2"></option>
    <option data-value="Chrome" value="3"></option>
    <option data-value="Opera" value="4"></option>
    <option data-value="Safari" value="5"></option>
</datalist>
<input id="submit" type="submit">```

<script>
function getRealValue(ele){
  var dl=ele.list.options;
  for (var x=0;x<dl.length;x++){
    if (dl[x].value==ele.value){
      ele.value=dl[x].dataset.value;
      return dl[x].dataset.value;
    }
  }
}
</script>
````