# datalist options with hidden values

Tags: html, user-interface

I have a standard [datalist](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element) along these lines:

```html
Building:
<input type=text id=building list=buildings>
<datalist id=buildings>
  <option value="b1234">Long name</option>
  <option value="b372">Other long name</option>
</datalist>
```

My goal is to show the user only the long names, but to send the short names on form submission. (The short names are meaningless to the end user, but the long names change often and are a poor choice for information interchange.)

How can I accomplish this? I can use `label`s but then the meaningless short names are shown and that's what I want to avoid.

I'm looking for a standards-compliant solution that works across popular browsers and degrades gracefully in the absence of Javascript. (Perhaps only the short names are shown, or perhaps both are.)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616625/how-to-display-the-text-in-datalist-html5-and-not-value?

Comment: You've already got the right idea.  The VALUE gets sent.  The text is what the user sees.

Comment: @j08691: That answer doesn't solve my problem because I want the form to work without Javascript.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want without JS.

Comment: @j08691: The intention is that it gracefully degrades without Javascript, perhaps showing the otherwise-hidden values.

Comment: @durbnpoisn: It works as desired in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Why not use the standard select?

Comment: @j08691: It's a long list and typing is faster than scrolling through a list.

Comment: @durbnpoisn: See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element

Comment: I still say you should be using a standard Select rather than a datalist.  There is no advantage to that at all.

Comment: @durbnpoisn: I need to allow inputs other than those in my list, so a `select` won't work for me.