# Hide value of a search input option

Tags: html, forms

When using a search input, the list is generally from a database, where the item will have an ID and a title. To make it easier to link what text value is selected from a search input, I usually set the value as the ID, as so:

```
<input type="search" list="mylist">
<datalist id="mylist">
  <option value="1">Example</option>
  <option value="2">Test</option>
  <option value="3">Another one</option>
</datalist>
```

But on chrome, and other browsers as far as I know, this results in the value being the "main" thing shown for the options, and the title is a sub-text underneath it.

From an end user perspective this looks awful:

[image: Awful input]

Is there any way to fix this so the "id" or value isn't visible, but that's still the value used when the form is submitted?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cgxnqrz/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting hidden datalist option values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086427/setting-hidden-datalist-option-values)

Comment: Why are you using `datalist` instead of normal `select` tag?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan so they can enter any text in the input if they want and are not limited to just the options

Comment: @tom looks like the only way to hide the value is to use a data attribute, put the label into the value and then submit the data value using javascript

Comment: @Wimanicesir I suupidly skipped that question based on the title, but it looks like the same issue yeah. I'll give it a go, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It needs to have integer value to be submitted, with a string as the visible content

Comment: <select>
  <option value="1">Example</option>
  <option value="2">Test</option>
  <option value="3">Another one</option>
</select>


use select 2 class to enable search in select drop down. On submitting you will get the integer value for DB and text string will be shown.

https://select2.org/searching


check this link