# DataList: How to hide the lookup value?

Tags: html, html-datalist

This question was edited because I found out is not related to VueJS but to HTML Datalist. I also closed this question as duplicate of [Setting hidden datalist option values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086427/setting-hidden-datalist-option-values).

Any selector in the world has a display property as label and a lookup value to link it with a list of objects. So far is ok. I need to hide the lookup id's that makes no sense form my users.

Every option entry of my selection list shows tho lines. The first line is the lookup-id that should not be presented to the user. The second line is the intended display-value (the label).

I need an option to hide the lookup value!
I can'e even find the HTML of the selection list, I assume is generated by the browser and not added to the DOM.

HLEP !!!

[image]

```
<div id="app">
    <datalist id="options1">  
    <option v-for="option in this.options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </datalist>

    <datalist id="options2">  
    <option v-for="option in this.options" v-bind:value="option" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </datalist>

    <datalist id="options3">  
    <option v-for="option in this.options" v-bind:value="option.name" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </datalist>

    I need to hide the IDs. <br>The display value should be displayed in the box after selection and the lookup value should be sent to the model (selectedId).<br>

    <input list="options1" v-model="selectedId" ><br>
    Selected ID is: {{ selectedId }}<br><br>

    LookupResult: {{ computedLookupById | json }}

    <hr><br><br>
    I was expecting that I can send the entire object to the model. But is actually a string.<br>
    <input list="options2" v-model="selectedOption" ><br>
    Selected ID is: {{ selectedOption | json }}<br><br>

    <hr><br><br>
    If I send the display value to the model, I have to lookup for the object. Will take computation time and will only work when display values are unique:<br>
    <input list="options3" v-model="selectedName" ><br>
    Selected ID is: {{ selectedName | json }}<br><br>

    LookupResult: {{ computedLookupByName | json }}
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>


<script>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      { id: 0, name: "one" }, // So, my display value is not unique. I can't use it for luckup.
      { id: 1, name: "one" },
      { id: 2, name: "two" },
      { id: 3, name: "tree" }
    ],
    selectedOption: null,
    selectedId: null,
    selectedName: null
  },
  computed: {
    computedLookupById() {
        return this.options.find(p => {
        return p.id == this.selectedId;
      });
    },
    computedLookupByName() {
        return this.options.find(p => {
        return p.name == this.selectedName;
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your code example?

Comment: ok, I see now your code. What exactly value do you want to hide?

Comment: Also, it would be great to see whole image of rendered component with region to hide.

Comment: I have added an answer. Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your computed:

```
computedLookupById() {
    return this.options.find(p => {
    return p.id == this.selectedId;
  });
},
```

`computedLookupById` return to you an object of option, for example, if `id` = 1, then returned value will be like this:

```
{ id: 1, name: "one" },
```

Within your template you have this line:

```
LookupResult: {{ computedLookupById | json }}
```

If you want to hide `id`, then you should do something like this:

```
LookupResult: {{ computedLookupById.name }}
```

Also it looks like `json` filter is removed from vue according to this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Built-In-Text-Filters-removed .

Comment: hi @webprogrammer, your analysis is correct but not solving my needs. I am not concerned about displaying the value, I made this example at the request of another user. I am highlighting the fact that a selection control should either 1) return the selected object (ideally), but this is not possible since the value is serialized to string, or 2) return the Id so that I can lookup myself for the object based on it's unique ID. This second case is possible but brings an annoying side-effect. The ID is displayed as first line in the option template, with no option to hide it.

Comment: Closed my own question (found out was not related to VueJS) as duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086427/setting-hidden-datalist-option-values