# Value and text shown same time on option button but i need just text

Tags: html

In my project i need to post to value of option button but i need to display a text not the option value. Both of them shown same time. Is there a way to not display the value.

My HTML code.

```
        <label style=" color: #ffebef; margin-left: 10px;">Başlangıç noktasını seçiniz
            <input list="browsers" style="border-color: rgba(1, 15, 13, 0.842); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" name="baslangic" /></label>
            <datalist id="browsers" >
              <option value="603">Bus Stop</option>
              <option value="276">Geomatics Engineering</option>
              <option value="649">Library</option>
            </datalist>
```

I tried many thing with style="" but i couldn't do that

[image]
It display bot of them

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: Hope this post is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086427/setting-hidden-datalist-option-values

Comment: Web Dev, As in the screenshot "603" and "Geomatics Engineering" displays but i need only Geomatics Engineering. Users Shouldn't see the 603

Comment: Thanks Royston Lau, when i used the first answer of it value shown as i want but when i use submit button it returns the value not id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **data- attr** and helper function for get value.

```
     <form action="/create" method="post" >
          <label style=" color: #ffebef; margin-left: 10px;">Başlangıç noktasını seçiniz
          <input id="inpbrowsers" list="browsers" style="border-color: rgba(1, 15, 13, 0.842); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" /></label>
           <datalist id="browsers" >
                        <option data-value="603">Bus Stop</option>
                        <option data-value="276">Geomatics Engineering</option>
                        <option data-value="649">Library</option>
                </datalist>
                
                <input type="hidden" id="baslangic"  name="baslangic">
                
                <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>

    <script>
     
            // fire on user selection
            $("#inpbrowsers").change(function(e){

                var value = e.target.value;
                var item = querySelectorIncludesText("#browsers option",value);
                // if find item
                if(item)
                {
                    $("#baslangic").val($(item).data("value"));

                }
                else
                {
                    $("#baslangic").val('');
                }
            });
            
            // helper function
            function querySelectorIncludesText (selector, text){    
                return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
                    .find(el => el.textContent.includes(text));
                }
    </script>
```

> **Updated** Now select item in datallist,baslangic get value. and submit form send value for your server[action].

[image]

you can download html page from [Github](https://github.com/thisisnabi/Stackoverflow-Helps/tree/master/Html_SelectFromDatalist)

Comment: Same situation continues as like in the screenshot but thanks sir

Comment: anything not changed. its just a sample from your code. you can copy it in your code.

Comment: First of all apologies for my mistake. When i use your code i got different error and also you realize about this situtation. Yes i use submit form and it didn't return the id, it returns text. Actually i cant understand what i need to do with hidden input button. If it doesn't bother you, can you explain that?

Comment: yes. I updating my answer. just wait

Comment: Your wellcome. Good job