# Show different text in datalist option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to show a different text than the value in `datalist option`. My `datalist` is the following:

```
<input type="text" list="result">

<datalist id="result"> 
    <option data-text="text1" value="1"/>
    <option data-text="text2" value="2"/>
    <option data-text="text3" value="3"/>
</datalist>
```

I just want to show a dropdown with the options `text1, text2, text3`, and insert the value in the input.

I think it's not possible, but I want to be sure.

Comment: And when you select option, you want it to be what in input?

Comment: @dfsq No, I want to insert the value 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Check this out: [How to display the text in datalist html5 and not value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616625/how-to-display-the-text-in-datalist-html5-and-not-value)

Comment: So use select box.

Comment: @pan.goth I want to do the opposite, in that example: I would like to show "Internet Explorer..." in the options and on click, insert value 1.

Comment: @dfsq I can't ,i'm doing a search to database and showing the results in a dropdown, I need the input and the datalist. The select tag is another input.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the text you want appear in the `listbox` between `<option>`. On click list this is the value replaced. Please try

Example with Text inside listbox and number (value) inserted into input:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="result">

<datalist id="result"> 
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</datalist>
```

Example with number (value) inside listbox and text inserted into input:

```js
$("#myInput").bind("select",function(){
    if($('#result').find('option').length) {
        if($('option[value='+this.value+']').length > 0){
          $("#myInput").val($('option[value='+this.value+']').data("text"));
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" list="result">

<datalist id="result"> 
    <option data-text="text1" value="1"/>
    <option data-text="text2" value="2"/>
    <option data-text="text3" value="3"/>
</datalist>
```

**Update**

```js
$("#myInput").bind("select",function(){
    if($('#result').find('option').length) {
        if($('option[value='+this.value+']').length > 0){
          $("#myInput").val($('option[value='+this.value+']').data("text"));
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" list="result">

<datalist id="result"> 
    <option data-text="Playstation" value="1">Text1</option>
    <option data-text="Xbox" value="2">Text2</option>
    <option data-text="Nintendo" value="3">Text2</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: @p-frank Yes but I don't want to show the value because it will be data from database and its not important for the user.

Comment: Ok but you say " I want to insert the value 1, 2 or 3" how you want insert this?

Comment: @p-frank It is inserted automatically. I just want to show text1 instead of 1.

Comment: There you display the option value, not the text.

Comment: See the update. You have all : text vs text  and text vs vale and value vs text.

Comment: @P.Frank That's not the solutions user is asking for, He wants now to show Value but the custom-attribute to client. Value is for backend purpose.