# JavaScript to set datalist by <input list="value"> for HTML5 on input/selection of value in another form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating my first Web Form and I'm looking for a little help getting this JavaScript Function to work for me.

I am trying to use a JavaScript function to specify which datalist to use for a form input list=" " based on the selected value of a separate form. As you can see below I have supplied the first form (which I intend to 'fire' the JavaScript and input the variable) and the second form which should have the input list=" " value set by the script. In the first form I have used two different events simply to figure out which is the appropriate: onselect= and onchange=.

I greatly appreciate any help or comments.

Here is my code, I have approached this quite a few different ways and at this point it exists as:

```
<form>
Tendon Type: <input list="tendontype">
<datalist id="tendontype">
    <option value="Cantilever" onselect="locationScript('ct')">
    <option value="Drape" onchange="locationScript('ut')">
    <option value="Span">
</datalist>
</form>

<form name="location">
Location: <input id="loc229" list="need js to insert here"><br />

<datalist id="pier">
    <option value="Pier EN-1">
    <option value="Pier EN-2">
</datalist>

<datalist id="unit">
    <option value="Unit EN-2">
    <option value="Unit EN-3">
</datalist>

<datalist id="span">
    <option value="Span EN-1">
    <option value="Span EN-2">
</datalist>
</form>

<script>
function locationScript(x) {
    var locationlist;
    if (x == 'ct') {
        locationlist = setAttribute("list","pier")
    } else {
        if (x == 'ut') {
            locationlist = setAttribute("list","unit")
        } else {
        locationlist = setAttribute("list","span")
        }
            }
        document.getElementById("loc229").locationlist;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: References: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027746/jquery-event-when-html5-datalist-option-is-clicked and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147728/input-list-selection-changed-event